# Passing constants in header function declaration

Tags: c, header-files

I've inherited about 1000 files that were written in C++ which I had to grudgingly convert to C. In one of the header files, a function is declared as

```
errnum DSPAPI aaCxSVD(complexnum *input_matrix,[...],intnum jobz=0);
```

which yields the following compilation error in XCode:

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token
```

if I simply do `intnum 0`, I get:

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant
```

if I remove intnum, I get:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
```

In the C file itself, different results get returned if jobz = 0 or not. Currently, it's the only header that ever mentions that function.

My question is thus: is there any legal way of doing this? is it even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jobz` has been given a *default value*.  This is a C++-only feature.

I would say that the easiest way to convert this is simply to remove the `=0`.  Then, find all locations where `aaCxSVD()` is being called without providing an explicit final parameter, and tack on `0`.

Comment: You could instead define a variadic macro that expands differently based on the number of arguments, and tack on an explicit 0 if there are too few.

Comment: @R..: I don't really use C99.  How does one do that?  Specifically, how does one get it to "expand differently based on the number of args"?